# How to pass string as model to partial view?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

May I know how to pass a string to partial view as a Model.

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new _DishItemCardModel {
        dishCode = "",
        dishName = "",
        dishPrice = ""
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

**Views**

```
@model ProjectName.Views.FoodMenu._DishItemCardModel

<partial name="_DishItemCard" model="new ProjectName.Views.FoodMenu._DishItemCardModel  { dishName = "test" }" />
```

**Partial View
_DishItem.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace ProjectName.Views.FoodMenu
{

    public class _DishItemCardModel
    {
        public string dishCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string dishName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string dishPrice { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**_DishItem.cshtml**

```
@model ProjectName.Views.FoodMenu._DishItemCardModel
        
<div>@Model.dishName</div>
<div>@Model.dishName</div>
<div>@Model.dishName</div>
```

**I get the error message:**

An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

```
Invalid expression term ';'
+
<partial name="_DishItemCard" model="new ProjectName.Views.FoodMenu._DishItemCardModel  { dishName = "test" }" />
} expected
+
<partial name="_DishItemCard" model="new ProjectName.Views.FoodMenu._DishItemCardModel  { dishName = "test" }" />
```

Comment: Need to escape double quotes around 'test'? `model="new ProjectName.Views.FoodMenu._DishItemCardModel { dishName = \"test\" }"`?

Comment: If you wanna write c# code in razor, you need to use `@(xxx)` to contain that code.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `@` symbol for C# code inside of a .cshtml file.

```
model="@(your C# code goes here)"
```

If you don't use the `@` symbol, it is parsed as a plain text string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Since your partial view is called _DishItem.cshtml

```
<partial name="_DishItem" model='new ProjectName.Views.FoodMenu._DishItemCardModel  { dishName = "test" }'>
```

For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0